# Una imagen queda arriba del header sticky

Tags: html, css

Tengo unas imagenes en modo slider en el index y al hacer scroll quedan por encima del header. Estoy recien empezando y me esta enquilombando esto. Se que hay formas mas faciles de hacer sliders pero es para un curso y tengo que ir de a poco. Ahora estoy usando solo html y css por eso esta así.

```
header{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: rgba(140, 80, 29, 0.659);
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
```

```
.container-slide{
    margin: auto;
    width: 800px;
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
}

ul.menu{
    padding: 50px;
}


ul.slider{
    position: relative;
    width: 800px;
    height: 300px;
}

ul.slider li{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    transition: opacity .5s;
}

ul.slider li img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 420px;
}

ul.slider li:first-child{
    opacity: 1;
}

ul.slider li:target{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

[image: Esto es lo que me pasa]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Añade la estructura del HTML, aplica las observaciones que se te mencionan arriba, es difícil proporcionar una respuesta correcta si no agregas lo necesario para comprender el problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Todo lo que sea de `position: fixed`, `position: sticky`, o `position: absolute` o cuando un objeto se quiere mostrar encima de otro objeto, debe ser con `z-index:`  mayor a todos los demás objetos que podría tener conflicto, o a su padre contenedor.

Por ejemplo, tu `header` no tiene `z-index` de ningún valor. Por ello, cuando se hace scroll, los demás objetos (o algunos) se sobreponen encima del `header`.

La razón a esto es porque el contenedor padre de tu imagen: `ul.slider li` es de posición absoluto, aunque éste no tenga un `z-index`

La solución simple y fácil es darle un `z-index` un tanto alto a tu `header`:

```
header{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: rgba(140, 80, 29, 0.659);
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Saludos

Comment: Gracias amigo ! Asi me quedo y aprendi lo que es z-index. Muchisimas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

1. el header debe estar en un padre relativo para que pueda fijarse al top y sticky pueda funcionar sobre todo el cuerpo del sitio
2. agrega un z-index superior a tu header para que los slides no se sobrepongan
3. ubica una position relativa a su contenedor de sliders y agrega un z-index inferior al del header.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomendaría cambiar el "sticky" por "fixed", te comparto una forma de hacerlo, espero te sea de ayuda.

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
    background-color:papayawhip;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
}

main {
    background-color: lightsalmon;
    height:150vh; /*Como ejemplo paa realizar scroll*/
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.slider{
    margin-top: 150px;
    height: 300px;
    width: 400px;
    border: solid 1px rgb(35, 33, 33);
}

section {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>Nav Bar</header>
    <main>
        <div class="slider">
            <div class="cardSlider"></div>
            <div class="cardSlider"></div>
            <div class="cardSlider"></div>
            <div class="cardSlider"></div>
        </div>
        <section>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Nobis placeat possimus natus nam amet unde quibusdam? Ratione architecto culpa natus repellat, sint alias voluptatem ipsam! Enim laudantium reiciendis unde ipsum!</p>
            <p>Doloremque aliquid nisi veritatis maxime nesciunt, dolor ea eligendi sint pariatur non repellendus ipsum minus quas. Laudantium, provident unde cum ipsum aspernatur aliquam debitis minima consequatur impedit, ratione, expedita ad?</p>
            <p>Sed, veritatis incidunt, similique nisi ex modi dolorem qui molestiae tempora quae, eos unde sapiente odio? Rem vitae quidem corrupti quo dolorem voluptatum quis fuga harum ipsa facilis, nostrum illo?</p>
            <p>Adipisci ducimus obcaecati nostrum nobis eligendi hic cum consequuntur velit corporis minima odit repellendus atque cupiditate fugit inventore dolore, nam ipsam? Voluptates, dignissimos dolore? Fugit, numquam laboriosam? Fugiat, odio neque?</p>
            <p>Magnam ex aperiam voluptatum illo error placeat necessitatibus repellat suscipit iure quae, numquam repudiandae vel optio quasi corporis asperiores praesentium obcaecati architecto veniam iste sapiente perferendis? Necessitatibus, facere doloribus. Aut.</p>
            <p>Placeat perferendis non in molestias repellendus labore quia minus magnam voluptatum natus ad quasi veniam accusamus, commodi velit qui ratione sapiente optio? Ducimus incidunt dolor natus vero provident laborum ipsum!</p>
            <p>Sunt maiores iure itaque unde recusandae. Cum dolor necessitatibus harum aspernatur modi laborum possimus facere minima, molestias nostrum reiciendis itaque odio laboriosam, soluta id ullam, omnis magnam ab a commodi?</p>
            <p>Sit magni soluta ipsa vitae. A pariatur laboriosam esse odio, laudantium, aliquid molestias culpa temporibus quibusdam ducimus dolore, magni qui eius mollitia architecto! Sapiente, hic reprehenderit fugiat dolor dicta error.</p>
            <p>Recusandae vel nisi impedit! Officiis eveniet nihil inventore deleniti hic perferendis, quos repudiandae in nemo. In quaerat voluptate nostrum porro tenetur, eius, alias maiores quod laudantium, pariatur rerum. Illo, nam?</p>
        </section>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```